# No Persistence provider for EntityManager named sample

Tags: hibernate, persistência

Quando utilizo a aplicação no Eclipse, com o tomcat8 ela roda sem problemas, dai gero o pacote utilizando o maven e faço o deploy no tomcat8 fora do eclipse e obtenho o erro abaixo. As jars estão vindo do maven e salvos na pasta WEB-INF/lib.

> 18-Feb-2017 17:10:52.957 GRAVE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandler.logException No Persistence provider for EntityManager named SistafPU
>    javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named SistafPU
>       at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:61)
>       at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
>       at br.mil.eb.sistaf.util.jpa.EntityManagerProducer.(EntityManagerProducer.java:18)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.newInstance(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:119)
>       at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.invokeAroundConstructCallbacks(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:92)
>       at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.newInstance(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:78)
>       at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.AbstractInstantiator.newInstance(AbstractInstantiator.java:28)
>       at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.produce(BasicInjectionTarget.java:116)
>       at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.produce(BeanInjectionTarget.java:175)
>       at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:158)
>       at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
>       at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:744)
>       at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.AbstractMemberProducer.getReceiver(AbstractMemberProducer.java:128)
>       at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.AbstractMemberProducer.produce(AbstractMemberProducer.java:148)
>       at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractProducerBean.create(AbstractProducerBean.java:183)
>       at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
>       at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:98)
>       at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.CachedBeanInstance.getInstance(CachedBeanInstance.java:66)
>       at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:99)
>       at org.jboss.weld.proxies.AutoCloseable$EntityManager$HibernateEntityManager$QueryProducer$Serializable$Session$SharedSessionContract$1573548027$Proxy$_$$*WeldClientProxy.unwrap(Unknown Source)
>       at br.mil.eb.sistaf.repository.Militares.filtrados(Militares.java:60)
>       at br.mil.eb.sistaf.repository.Militares$Proxy$*$$_WeldSubclass.filtrados(Unknown Source)
>       at br.mil.eb.sistaf.controller.PesquisaMilitaresBean.pesquisar(PesquisaMilitaresBean.java:53)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
>       at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
>       at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
>       at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.DeclarativeSystemEventListener.processEvent(EventHandler.java:128)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent$ComponentSystemEventListenerAdapter.processEvent(UIComponent.java:2584)
>       at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:108)
>       at javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent.processListener(ComponentSystemEvent.java:118)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2169)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeComponentListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2114)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:287)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:245)
>       at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:726)
>       at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:726)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:107)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
>       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

meu persistence.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
 xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">


 <!-- Apache Derby -->
 <persistence-unit name="SistafPU">
         <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
         
 
         <properties>
          <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect" />
             <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
             <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:/home/melquiades/SistafDB;create=true" />
             <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="melquiades" />
             <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="melquiades" />
             <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
             <property name="format_sql" value="true" />
             <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />
             <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
             
             
   
         </properties>
 </persistence-unit>
 

</persistence>
```

Ja estou a dois dias tentando resolver isso, ja tentei colocar os jars do hibernate direto na pasta, ja troquei META-INF para a pasta scr, enfim não consegui resolver. Qualquer norte já ajuda, sou iniciante nessas tecnologias e não sei por mais onde correr.

ps. o tomcat que utilizo no eclipse é o mesmo que esta fora.
ps2. ja vi muitos tópicos desses aqui no stackoverflow mas nenhum sanou meu problema